Can't invert an RGB 8 bits per channel PNG using ImageOps
I'm attempting to invert an image.
It fails with an RGB PNG file that has 8 bits per channel (so no alpha).  Any ideas why? (It works on every other image I throw at it other than these five ones that are PNG and that's the only thing I can find in common with them.
Note: nearly all the other images I try are JPG, so I'm guessing it's something to do with PNG but I can't find out what.
Code:
from PIL import Image
import PIL.ImageOps
im = Image.open(image_file)
inverted_image = ImageOps.invert(im)

I get this error message:
<class 'OSError'>, File: None, Line: 58, Function: _lut <class 'AttributeError'>, File: unknown, Line: unknown, Function: unknown


Can you provide 1) the image that fails 2) the error message, and 3) the traceback for the error?

Not sure what a traceback is but here's a link to an image that fails: https://mega.nz/file/V6AClRTA#Rga3KlvWnz2wb8S5xwVxHMMTlvkn9_jYJfGwOFyCFVA   and the error it fails with is <class 'OSError'>,  File: None,  Line: 58,  Function: _lut
<class 'AttributeError'>,  File: unknown,  Line: unknown,  Function: unknown

Thanks. Are you sure this is an RGB image? When I print im.mode, I get 'RGBA'. When I try to invert the image using your code, I get the error OSError: not supported for mode RGBA inside the function _lut. I think that may be the cause of your error.

Hmmm - okay, I was looking at the mode inside of Photoshop (where I only see "RGB 8 bits per channel" which I assumed couldn't have alpha because, well, only 8 bits and no alpha layer) but maybe you're right.  Let me try the code that works with even RGBA and see if that solves the problem.

FWIW, I looked at the alpha channel of your image, and it's 255 everywhere. So you could probably just discard the alpha channel.

Yep, you are correct - it IS an RGBA image.  Sigh - wish I had known that (I should have just checked the im.mode for it).  And my code to handle it works fine (it's documented elsewhere in StackOverflow so I won't repeat  - essentially if you test it first and it's alpha you then Split the image and merge it with the RGB option).  But thanks!

This WAS an RGBA image so my bad (again, I'm not sure how to delete these things if the answer is simple).
With such an image you can test first (with .mode) and if RGBA then you can write code which splits and then merges the result (documented here in another thread where someone wants to handle RGBA images and invert them).
The real "answer" is you have to test via mode because looking at it elsewhere (I looked in Photoshop and it did NOT show an alpha channel there) is not enough.
